# Component's description in Nexus Repository

Tags: components, nexus, artifacts, nexus3

I have Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3.9.0-01 with some local hosted repositories.
There are a lot of different private components and I want to add some description for each of them. For example: full name, what problem does this component solve, maybe some release notes and others.

How can I do it? Maybe there are existed some plugins or other solutions?